# how to mount host directory to docker container with proper user:group map?

Tags: linux, docker

I use `docker run -v <local dir>:<in docker path>` to mount a local dir. The container expecting a proper user:group of the paths, for exmaple, mongodb or sambashare. However, the numeric id inside the container and my host do not match. Is there a canonical way to handle this problem? Should I use something like bindfs to map it?

If I use bindfs to map the user ids before I use `-v` to mount, then it works. But I would like to do this inside docker. Is there a way to do this?